# RSS Feed blocked as insecure even though SSL is enabled

Tags: ssl, rss

I am pulling RSS content from a WordPress blog with Google Feeds API. When navigating to https://wordpress-domain.org/feed SSL is in the clear (padlock). However, on the site the content is meant to display, browsers are blocking the site from pulling the RSS content due to it being "insecure".

Surely I don't have to pass the feed content through an encryption/decryption protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It appears that the issue was so simple that I looked over it. The reference to Google's Feed API in the javascript file was not loading in SSL. Fixed the link and all is well.